# How to apply the same transition effect as slideshow images to their caption

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using JQuery Cycle on some images and have them working perfectly, however, I dont like the way their accompanying captions change, they jar in contrast to the image fade I have.

I want to apply the same transition effect to their captions. Do you know how to do it?

I'm sure this is an easy one, but not for me. I've included the plugin, with my settings in the js. Here is a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/NQE8b/

Also, have a problem with the images jumping on load, so another issue to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have your captions in the same div as your slideshow?  That's why you're getting inconsistencies.  There are a couple of ways to approach this, but I would do it with lists.

So try this:

```
   <div id="images_caption">
   <ul id="slideshow" class="pics">
   <li><img src=http://www.cressidahaughton.co.uk/blackout%202jan31.jpg alt=""/>
   <br />TITLE 1<br />medium<br />size<br />date</li>
   <li><img src=http://www.cressidahaughton.co.uk/blackout%201jan31.jpg alt=""/>
   <br />TITLE 2<br />medium<br />size<br />date</li>
   <li><img src=http://www.cressidahaughton.co.uk/blackout4jan31.jpg alt=""/>
   <br />TITLE 3<br />medium<br />size<br />date</li>
   </ul>       
   </div>
```

Just make sure your divs and /divs match.